Why is there an installing window when I open the sample app built by electron?

I am learning to use electron to build a Windows desktop application. When I built an application using the official quick start tutorial (https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start), two windows appeared when I opened it. One is the hello world window, and the other is the installing window. I don't understand why this installing window appears, because my program itself should not need to be installed, it should be a single exe program. Am I wrong? How can I avoid the installing window appearing in the exe program built using electron technology?

Squirrel.Windows generates an installer, not a portable app.

thanks，how to make the installing window disappear？

If you speak about the green thing, the option is called loadingGif
